# Converting site to Drupal -- the nightmare has begun

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I'm trying to convert site www.mircscripts.org to Drupal, and researching more and more about migration I've been getting more and more confused.

There are various modules that supposidly will help with the migration process, but these are nothing but confusing and all lack in either a. documentation (listen up Migrate module!) or b. only support Drupal 6.

The Migration Module you seem to have to dive into PHP code and create some "mappings" to your old table data and Drupal. First off, I would ideally like a GUI (Table Wizard only supports Drupal 6 it seems, and the superseded Data module only Drupal 6 too). I also want to import data into Drupal and not use "mappings." I want to be able to disable the Migrate module after all the data has been "converted" to be Drupal node compatible.

If you take a look at the site above, you can pretty much see the scale of data, forum, comments, etc and get an idea of how the database tables look, just your usual stuff; users, comments, and more custom stuff like "files" which stores all the different scripts uploaded by users.

Any suggestions on how I would I go about converting the site?

Cheers

Gary

**edit**: I forgot to mention the site is almost entirely custom made. The code for it looks like my nan on her way to bingo -- a complete mess. There is an interesting bit of code available at http://drupal.org/node/261066 if you scroll down, although I don't feel like doing `node_save()` 60,000 times for every record, for just one table. It sounds evil.

Comment: Migrating a big site is often not a simple operation, and can require a large amount of coding... Good luck !

Comment: I wouldn't try shoehorning your old site into Drupal, it'll just make the nightmare neverending. Build a new site in Drupal, with one eye on data you want to transfer over. Take what you can and ditch the rest / start over. Seems a little harsh but you'll thank yourself for it.

Comment: Also Drupal's a pain for doing custom work with (in my opinion). Take a look at http://pyrocms.com/ or http://codeigniter.com/

Comment: It might sound evil, but there's no other way (short of adding the data using just SQL, but make sure you understand how Drupal data is structured before even attempting that). For a nice intro to Migrate, just have a look at [Migration: Not Just for the Birds](http://www.archive.org/details/DrupalconDc2009-MigrationNotJustForTheBirds)

Comment: @logic-unit: Taking a look at pyrocms.com and reading some reviews, I can say I'm staying well clear. The site promotes "open source cms" but has a distinctive "add-ons" section, selling add-ons for a few quid. And apparently the developers are extremely rude on IRC. If I'm going to devote a lot of my time to learing a CMS system, I'd rather go with a reputable and respected one.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you migrating to?

Comment: @wimvds thanks for the link. It's useful, but that is using Table Wizard, which isn't available for Drupal 7. @googletorp, Drupal 7 am migrating to.

Comment: @Gary Green fair enough.

Comment: @Gary Green also, are you looking for a solution to this problem that is free, and doesn't require any coding?

Comment: @logic-unit, yes it has to be a free solution. I'm very comfortable in PHP and MySQL, developing all my sites usually from scratch. If I do have to create code, I'd like to be pointed in the direction of some good guides for importing data efficiently to be compatible with Drupal nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at feeds. It's a GUI importer thing that allows you to map fields in a file to objects like nodes.

http://drupal.org/project/feeds

There's nothing evil about node_save over all the rows in your table. That's essentially what any import module should do anyway. I worked on a huge d5 project where we imported millions of nodes that way. It works fine.

Some people have recommended saving to the database directly. Never do that. It's just not the right way to create nodes. Use the Drupal API!

Comment: One thing to note with node_save- it ensures all other modules/implementations can interact with your content (like pathauto for instance). So while it may be slow in some cases, its critical to use.

Answer (score 3):

The migration module comes with an example migration module and some documentation to facilitate content migrations. Dozens of sites have utilized this to achieve migration. It is not a GUI point and click but very flexible and can be tested repeatedly.

I've written my own modules before to do custom migrations prior to this, and its not as bad as it sounds. You just need to know how the schema relates and map it on paper, then pseudocode and test.

For www.dogfish.com, I migrated 12,000 some nodes. For a band site I am trying to relaunch, I have migrated 75,000+ nodes. Both methods I utilized a db connection and cron to get the next X results. I could have also used BatchAPI but that seemed slower.

Migrate module is the way to go.

Comment: One thing I never understood about the migration module is does it actually *import* data or does it just create a mapping?

Comment: Through its API, you will create the mappings, and tell it what to do with the data as it processes. Check this out: http://drupal.org/node/1006984 and see the example code in the module. It provides a simple script to show a demonstration of a basic migration.

Answer (score -2):

As i have spent years on drupal. I did not see any full fledged module for migration. Its better you start coding, it will save time and that the smart idea :)